# Acer Aspire keyboard prints random letters and Fn combinations does not work

Tags: keyboard, acer-aspire, fn-key

I have Acer Aspire 5742ZG and today I realized that my keyboard stared to work incorrect. For example Fn + F[1-9] does not work while Fn + right/left arrow change sound and up/down change brightness and some general keys also does not work properly for example + on num pad will -print /+ and + also will print /+

I read several topics and people suggest to press FN+NumLock or FN+F10/F11 but in my case this does not help.

May be someone can suggest another option

Comment: What happened before this issue? Beverage spill? OS update? Program installation?

Comment: Hi @DrMoishePippik, I do not think that software updates could cause this because I tried to boot up with linux liveCD and same issue with keyboard also reproduces on liveCD.

Comment: Again: beverage spill? Also: pressure on case or keyboard? Dropped? It could be a stuck key, conductive glop on PC traces, a broken trace on the keyboard connector, a loose keyboard connector... help to narrow the possibilities with more information.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, nothing from the above. I just watched a video and then wanted to google something and realized that keys work in inappropriate way. I decided to bring my laptop to local repair center because even OS reinstall and BIOS updates have not fixed that issue.